# NULL response from SOAP exposed from servicenow to get incident number details?

Tags: c#, soap-client, webservice-client, servicenow

I have written following code in c#.net to fetch the details about a ticket from servicenow using SOAP service exposed to me. But the response I am getting is always null.

WSDL url: https://domainname.service-now/incident.do?WSDL

Code:

```
private static void readSnowTicket()
    {
        // Create incident in servicenow
        Ticket_Status.SNOW.ServiceNowSoapClient soapClient = new Ticket_Status.SNOW.ServiceNowSoapClient();
        soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SNOWUsername"].ToString();
        soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SNOWPassword"].ToString();

        try
        {
            SNOW.getRecords getRec = new SNOW.getRecords();
            getRec.sys_id = "3xxx9299xxx42b005x93xx9xxx9619b3";

            var outputresult = soapClient.getRecords(getRec);
            //insertresponse = soapClient.insert(insert);
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ErrorInsertingIncident)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error - " + ErrorInsertingIncident.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have created a service reference named "SNOW".
outputresult variable is always null.

This is not an authority issue as I have used another service reference in same program to create an incident ticket using u_incident_creation.do WSDL which is returning the insert response correctly.

NOTE: 
1. I have made the required changes in config file of the application for security.

2. I have made necessary changes to service now as mentioned in the link mentioned: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-application-development/page/integrate/examples/task/t_ConfigureCSharpWith.NET.html

3. SOAP service are returning values by passing sys_id parameter if used via chrome extension wizdler (using same credentials).

Comment: Is your exception handler hit?

Comment: No exceptions. the code runs fine, but the return variable is null.

Comment: Have you tried it WCFTestClient.exe? You might also [enable tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing), though traces are not easy to read.

Comment: Tested via SOAPUI and Wizdler, both are returning values.

Comment: Yes, but WCFTestClient generates a proxy exactly like you get with a Service Reference. It may help narrow down the issue.

Comment: WCFTestClient does not allow to pass basic authentication which is required to access the service exposed.